# Invalid convert from std::sqlString to char const* in C++ and Mysql

Tags: c++, mysql

```
con->setSchema(DATABASE);
// Query section
stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  `submission` WHERE  'status' = 0");
while (res->next()) {
 // Access column data by alias or column name 
 string insert = res->getString('pid');
 const char* p = insert.c_str();

  pipe = fopen(p, 'w');

  fprintf(pipe,"Successfully created");
}
```

How can i convert the `res->getString('pid')` value into `fopen()` as filename. I get error because its asking for `char const*`

Comment: FYI, you have the wrong type of quotes around `status`, they should be backticks. You're comparing the literal string `'status'` to `0`.

Comment: @_bastin-robin WTH is `std::sqlString`?? Can you enlighten me please, I've never seen that.

Comment: hi @πάνταῥεῖ actually my program is watching the database and getting the number of rows with status = 0 (false) and using the primary key of each row to create a pipe. So wht problem occurs is when i use the res->getString('pid') it returns me std::sqlString which i am not able to pass into the fopen(filename, "w") as filename as its only accepting char const *.

Comment: @Barmar even though that is wrong i am able to fetch the data according to my condition from my database but not able to convert my primary keys into char const* which is going to be the filename in fopen(). Have any idea??

Comment: @BastinRobin There's no such thing as a `std::sqlString`, not that I know about it at least.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the data we get after doing res->getString('pid') is called sqlString. But finally i sorted the problem.. Check my answer below

Comment: @BastinRobin So you meant a SQL statement contained in a `std::string`? Then the answer probably boils down to use the `std::string::c_str()` when passing the value to an API that requires a `const char*` as parameter. Be precise when asking please and show at least the types used for the variables shown in your samples.

Answer (score 1):

```
con->setSchema(DATABASE);
// Query section
stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  `submission` WHERE  'status' = 0");
while (res->next()) {
// Access column data by alias or column name 

string insert = res->getString('pid'); //changed 'pid' to "pid"

const char* p = insert.c_str();

FILE *pipe = fopen(p, 'w'); // Declared pipe as FILE

fprintf(pipe,"Successfully created");
}
```